# Layout components in a semi circle using CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a page which needs to display 5 rounded components (images) of varying size and I'd like to display them in sort of a semi circle pattern. The attached image displays roughly how I want the layout to look (imagine custom images in those circles). The images are going to be set dynamically through javascript (and Angular) which is why I've currently kept the image definition in the HTML.

[image: Semi Circle layout]

Currently I'm making my images rounded, manually resizing them and then manually moving them them using transform: translate(x,y) to create my semi circle pattern. The problem is that this isn't very dynamic and if I want to resize my images I need to redo the math to make a 'perfect circle'.

This is the code for what I'm currently doing:

```
<div class="round top1st" style="background-image: url('image1.png');"></div>
<div class="round top2nd" style="background-image: url('image2.png');"></div>
.
.
.

.round {
    border-radius:50% 50% 50% 50%;  
    overflow: hidden;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}

.top1st {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    transform: translate(0px,300px);
}

.top2nd {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    transform: translate(100px, -30px);
}
.
.
.
```

Could someone recommend a better/more efficient way to do this? Please also keep in mind that my images need to be various sizes of circles and that they images themselves are going to be set dynamically (queried from a DB and passed back to the client using Angular).

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would do it this way.

asuming your container has a height (whatever px or %) I would use all the rest of sizes with percent and position the circles with `position:absolute` with just `top`and `bottom`insteed of translate (also with per cent values).

This way your circles will be absolutely responsive.

the only problem is to make the circle perfect as you have a width with % so here I would use a bit of jquery to calc the real width of the element and give same value to height:

```
var cw = $('.top1st').width();
$('.top1st').css({
    'height': cw + 'px'
});
```

css:

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#ddd;
}
.round {
    border-radius:50% 50% 50% 50%;  
    overflow: hidden;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
}
.top1st {
    width: 20%;
    bottom:10%;
    left:8%;
}
.top2nd {
    width: 18%;
    bottom:40%;
    left:28%;
}
.top3nd {
    width: 16%;
    bottom:45%;
    left:50%;
}
.top4nd {
    width: 14%;
    bottom:35%;
    left:70%;
}
.top5nd {
    width: 12%;
    bottom:15%;
    left:85%;
}
```

This values are, of course to be changed for you to position the elements as You wish, I have just made a fast aproach. You can see the result in this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/y5x01vfg/3/)**

The only "little" problem is that if you resize the window the circles will get deformed till you reload the page. which shoudn't be a problem as users don't often do that, they will just have the circles well positioned on whatever platform they are using